# How to rearrange table after deleting first row in sqlite?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I have 1 table in sqlite, I am inserting values to that table. when the insertion row id greater than 100 I want to delete first inserted record and insert new record at 100th location, I am deleted 1st record but 2nd record in 2nd place but i want rearrange the record after deleting first row. How can I do it?

My table name is: Products

My table contains productName,productId,...

My DatabaseName is: HalalGauge.sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your new row as productId 101.
DELETE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE productId = 1
UPDATE PRODUCTS set productId = (productId-1)

I wouldn't call this a nice solution as it updates every row but if you only have 100 rows it will be ok.

Comment: ProductID in my App gives random values may i use rowid instead of that?

Comment: DELETE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE rowID = 1 UPDATE PRODUCTS set rowID = (rowID-1)
is it Correct?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this methods for rearranging

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
         forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
         toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath;
```