# Android SQLite update all ids after delete row

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

My English is not very good. Sorry. I am trying to learn to do Android application. But I have a problem. I'm adding Android SQlite content. And I'm getting them one by one. I do previous and next paging with buttons.  `Next = id+1`,`Previous = id-1`
So far everything is normal. But when I delete these contents id remains empty.

eg.
**id - name - age**

1  - Name - 26

2  - Name - 32

3  - Name - 31

4  - Name - 21

when I delete the id content 2

**id - name - age**

1  - Name - 26

3  - Name - 31

4  - Name - 21

I can't getting content because id is empty when I press Next button.
How can I solve this problem? 
Can I reset the id values after each deletion?

**id - name - age**

1  - Name - 26

2  - Name - 31

3  - Name - 21

Please help me.

Comment: You may check this one, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6067728/7316510

Answer (score 2):

you need to get all row from table one in list and the on next and previous button iterate list like this.
int currentIndex=0

```
     nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(currentIndex<dataList.size()-1)
                    {
                     currentIndex++;
                     setCurrentItem(dataList.get(currentIndex));
                    }
                }
            });
 previuosButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(currentIndex>0)
                    {
                     currentIndex--;
                     setCurrentItem(dataList.get(currentIndex))
                    }
                }
            });
```